# Dreamweaver CSS code erased

Tags: css, web, dreamweaver

After I preview my website, the CSS code suddenly disappear and was saved. Does anyone know how to recover it?

I still have the website correctly preview in Chrome. Is there any way that I could get the code from there?

I was almost ending the website, so another 3 weeks battling.

Comment: Is the CSS code inline or in a seperate file? Can you post any screenshots so I can understand what you're saying a bit more.

Comment: Hi mate, is in a separate file, I managed to copy almost the entire css line by line from the preview in chrome, it took me 4h to analaze every thing, some classes were missing,  but I guess that is better than 1 month of coding down the toilet.... cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the source code with Ctrl + U, then click external stylesheet link, copy the code and paste it in a new stylesheet.

NOTE: Don't refresh before doing this.

Comment: Thank you for the tip it helped to get some very well hiden code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have it on a separate css file, you should be able to go into Chrome developer tools and select Sources. This will show you the attached css files. You can then copy and paste it.

Comment: I couldn't find the separate css like that was wierd, thank you for the help, and tips! Cheers